# Phing: Backup folder to local area network

Tags: phing

i am using phing to backup the database folder of an eclipse project. i want to copy the folder (C:\xampp\mysql\data[projectname]) to a local area network folder (\[ip adress of backup computer]\projekte[projectname]\db). The according script is

```
<target name="copy_to_lan" description="copy db files to local area network">
    <echo>Remove ${lan_folder}...</echo>
    <delete dir="${lan_folder}" includeemptydirs="true" failonerror="true" />

    <echo>Copying files from ${local_db_folder} to ${lan_folder} ..</echo>
    <copy todir="${lan_folder}" verbose="true" includeemptydirs="true">
        <fileset dir="${local_db_folder}">
            <include name="**" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

Unfortunately, when executing the script, the eclipse tells
IOException: No read access to \[ip adress of backup computer]\projekte[projectname]\db[projectname] in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\phing\system\io\PhingFile.php on line 443.

Deleting and making a folder on the backup computer do work properly, but copying the files does not due to permission errors, as it seems to be. As an alternative i did also create the folder on the backup computer by mkdir, which works but ends with the same problem, that the files could not be transferred.

thanks for any advise

Comment: Did you try to map the remote location as a system drive in Windows first? Then you would copy for example to p:\projekte.... instead of \192.168.1.5\....

Comment: I think you have permission problems here. Can you copy the files with another program (i.e. Explorer) to the exact same location?

Comment: I have a similar problem with the mkdir command in phing. It seems it doesn't work with network drives. I already tried executing the shell as administrator but this doesn't work either. On a local drive it's working fine.

Comment: @jiriki: did you had time to try this one out in the meantime (which lasts over two years now ;-) )?

Comment: @poisson Old question, answer and comment. Still, I want to add that mapping a drive letter to a network location yields the same result. I even tried "mklink" to map a local folder to a network location (using Windows 10 by the way). Also fails. The answer user acme wrote is still applicable as of today, it seems.

Answer (score 4):

I found this [slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/eljefe/automated-deployment-with-phing) which mentions on slide #29 that the phing copy tasks do not work over network. You have to use native windows commands (e.g. xcopy or robocopy since Windows Vista) instead, called in the phing `exec` command.

So **on windows** instead of using a phing task like

```
<mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
```

use

```
<exec passthru="1" command="mkdir ${build.dir}" />
```

or in your case for copying instead of

```
<copy todir="${lan_folder}" verbose="true" includeemptydirs="true">
    <fileset dir="${local_db_folder}">
        <include name="**" />
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

use

```
<exec passthru="1" command="robocopy ${local_db_folder} ${lan_folder} /MIR" />
```

or

```
<exec passthru="1" command="xcopy ${local_db_folder}\*.* ${lan_folder} /I /Y /E" />
```

The flags mean:

- **/I**: If destination does not exist and copying more than one file, assumes that destination must be a directory
- **/Y**: Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file
- **/E**: Copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones

The `passthru` attribute is optional but it outputs windows errors on those commands, useful for debugging.

That works with network drives.